# I want to use left property but I dont want a certain coordinate I want to use left in a functio such that every time the func is called it move 10 px

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
       $( "#animateCanvas" ).click(function() {

        $("#myCanvas").css({top: 0, left : x+20, position:'relative'});
        $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left:100, position:'relative'});
    });
 $( "#animationgallery" ).click(function() {
        $("#myCanvas").css({top: 0, left: 500, position:'absolute'});
        $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left: 500, position:'absolute'});
    });
```

I want everytime I click on animate canvas the element moves left not only one time but everytime

can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: Where is `x` value ? You should increment this value inside the click function after the movement.

Comment: The issue is that if initiated x in the method every time the method is called it'll return to it's original value

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#animateCanvas" ).click(function() {
    $("#myCanvas").css({top: 0, left : x+20, position:'relative'});
    $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left:100, position:'relative'});
});

$( "#animationgallery" ).click(function() {
    $("#myCanvas").css({top: 0, left: 500, position:'absolute'});
    $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left: 500, position:'absolute'});
});
```

You could go with `Core972`'s answer but if it's going to be a linear progression you could do something like this instead:

```
$( "#animateCanvas" ).click(function() {
    $("#myCanvas").animate({
        'left' : '+=30px'    
    });  
    $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left:100, position:'relative'});
});
```

That way you don't need a variable declared/initialised.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6zpkefL9/

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate `x` before the function and then use it inside.

```
let x = 0;
$( "#animateCanvas" ).click(function() {

    x += 20;
    $("#myCanvas").css({top: 0, left : x, position:'relative'});
    $("#myCanvas2").css({top: 100, left:100, position:'relative'});
});
```